# How can I get distinct query results in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a user table in which there is column Id. I need to fetch rows which do not have duplicate value for Id column. For Example, this is my table structure

> ID  - Name - Email
>    1---    xxx ------  xx 
>    2---    xxx-------   xx 
>    2---    xxx ------ xx 
>    1---    xxx------- xx

```
public function allUsers(Request $request)
{
    $this->updateOnlineStatus($request);

    $query = UsersList::query();

    $query->addSelect('users_list_view.user_type');

    $scoreDate = $request->get('score_date');
    if ($scoreDate &&
        (trim($scoreDate['from']) !== ''
            || trim($scoreDate['to']) !== '')
    ) {
        $query->selectSub(function ($q) use ($scoreDate) {
            $q->select(DB::raw('AVG(fortune_scores.score)*20 AS score'))
                ->from('fortune_scores')
                ->leftJoin('fortunes', 'fortunes.id', '=', 'fortune_scores.fortune_id')
                ->whereRaw('fortunes.user_id = users_list_view.id')
                ->distinct('id')
                ->get();


            if (trim($scoreDate['from']) !== '') {
                $scoreDate['from'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $scoreDate['from'] . ' 00:00:00');
                $q->where('fortune_scores.created_at', '>=', $scoreDate['from'])
                ->distinct('id')
                ->get();
            }

            if (trim($scoreDate['to']) !== '') {
                $scoreDate['to'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $scoreDate['to'] . ' 23:59:59');
                $q->where('fortune_scores.created_at', '<=', $scoreDate['to'])
                ->distinct('id')
                ->get();
            }

            return $q;

        }, 'percentage');

        $query->selectSub(function ($q) use ($scoreDate) {
            $q->select(DB::raw('COUNT(1) AS count'))
                ->from('fortunes')
                ->whereRaw('fortunes.user_id = users_list_view.id')
                ->whereIn('fortunes.status', [FortuneStatus::COMMENT_SENT, FortuneStatus::PENDING_ANSWER, FortuneStatus::ANSWER_SENT])
                ->distinct('id')
                ->get();
            if (trim($scoreDate['from']) !== '') {
                $scoreDate['from'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $scoreDate['from'] . ' 00:00:00');
                $q->where('fortunes.updated_at', '>=', $scoreDate['from'])
                ->distinct('id')
                ->get();
            }

            if (trim($scoreDate['to']) !== '') {
                $scoreDate['to'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $scoreDate['to'] . ' 23:59:59');
                $q->where('fortunes.updated_at', '<=', $scoreDate['to'])
                ->distinct('id')
                ->get();
            }
        }, 'fortune_count');
    }


    $dataTable = new DataTableService($query, collect($request->except('score_date')));

    return $dataTable->setResultMap(function ($item) {
        $statusClass = $item->online_status == 0 ? 'danger' : ($item->online_status == 1 ? 'yellow-lemon' : 'green-jungle');
        $statusName = $item->online_status == 0 ? 'çevrimdışı' : ($item->online_status == 1 ? 'meşgul' : 'çevrimiçi');

        return [
            'id' => $item->id,
            'name' => $item->name,
            'online_status' => '<span class="label label-' . $statusClass . '">' . $statusName . '</span>',
            'balance' => ($item->balance ? $item->balance : 0) . " TL",
            'fortune_count' => ($item->user_type == UserType::RANDOM_TELLER ? User::find($item->id)->fortuneCount() : $item->fortune_count),
            'percentage' => number_format($item->percentage, 2) ?: '0',
            'credit' => $item->credit,
            'last_login' => $item->last_login ? Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $item->last_login)->format('d.m.Y H:i:s') : '',
            'action' => '<a href="' . route('admin.user.detail', ['id' => $item->id]) . '" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline grey-salsa" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Detay</a>',
        ];
    })->get();

}
```

I tried "get, distinct, select, count" but not working on my code?

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Try running ->unique() after ->get(). It is collection method. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-unique